# How can I use the translation theorem to show that two inverse Laplace transforms are the same?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use partial fractions to find the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s) =\large \frac{s+1}{s^3+5s^2+6s}$.  Then use $u = s+1$ to show that $F(s) = G(u) = \large\frac{u}{(u-1)(u+1)(u+2)}$.

Use partial fractions to find the inverse Laplace transform of $G(s)$, and then use the translation theorem to show that the inverse transforms of $F(s)$ and $G(s+1)$ are the same.

I found the inverse Laplace transforms of $F(s)$ and $G(s)$ using partial fractions as:

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\} = f(t) = \frac{1}{6}-\frac{2}{3}e^{-3t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2t}$$

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{G(s)\} = g(t) = \frac{1}{6}e^{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}-\frac{2}{3}e^{-2t}$$

Now I'm having trouble using the translation theorem to show that $F(s)$ and $G(s+1)$ are the same.  Can some explain exactly what the translation theorem allows us to conclude and how it can possibly relate to this problem?

Comment: You are missing a cube on the deffinition of $F(s)$ I think.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I assume is the so called *Translation Theorem* is simply a property of the Laplace transfom, i.e
$$
\mathcal{L}\{e^{-at} f(t)\} = \int_0^\infty e^{-s t} e^{-a t}f(t) dt = \int_0^\infty e^{-(s+a)t}f(t) dt
$$
and denoting
$$
F(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-s t} f(t) dt
$$
then
$$
F(s+a) = \mathcal{L} \{e^{-a t} f(t)\}.
$$

In your case, you have that $F(s) = G(s+1)$, and then
$$
f(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\} = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{G(s+1)\} = e^{-t} g(t)
$$